# What's the probability that a baby will be born healthy?

Tags: probability

Here's a little 'real life' mathematics problem. I think it's most likely trivial. Forgive me - I don't much about statistics/probability.

We all want babies to be born healthy. However, there's always various diseases babies can be born with. For example, out of every thousand babies, [it is estimated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congenital_heart_defect) that somewhere between $6$ and $19$ of them are born with a congenital heart defect that causes "a moderate to severe degree of problems" (from Wikipedia). There's many other congenital defects. These can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congenital_disorder)

The probability for a baby to be born with a *particular* defect is generally quite low. It's often lower than $1$% or $0.1$%.
However, the issue is that there's *lots* of defects. I'm not a doctor, but I would assume that the number of possible 'defects' would be in the thousands, or perhaps tens of thousands. Given this, it comes as quite a surprise to me that the vast majority of babies are born healthy.

So, here's the problem. Let's suppose we have a finite nonempty disease set $S$ (so, $|S| = n, n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$) and function $p:S \to (0,1)$ which assigns to each disease the likelihood that the baby will be born with that disease. The baby can be born healthy, or, alternatively, he or she can suffer from several of these diseases.

What is the likelihood that the baby will be born healthy?

Comment: If you make the (unlikely) assumption that each occurrence of a defect is an independent event and equally likely to occur at each birth, then the probability that a baby will avoid all $n$ of them is $\prod (1-p_n)$.

Comment: To stress, however:  those assumptions are quite unphysical.  Lots of these factors will be correlated to externals (age/health of the mother for a big one, genetic history of the parents, strong prenatal care, and so on) so assuming independence and equal probability for all kids is not sensible.

Comment: +1 to lulu, it's quite hard to give an "acceptable" answer to this unless you are fine with the highly unrealistic assumption that each birth is i.i.d.

Comment: @q.Then or switch to a non controversial problem : probability to die healthy...